# Angular2, persisting service results across components

Tags: angular

Trying to create a login service (`AuthService`) for an Angular 2 application, and I keep running into things I'm not expecting. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a single user object that, after login, is used everywhere in the application. If the user logs out and back in, the user should be changing in the other components by fetching it in the `ngOnInit` function.

```
class Service {
    private user: User;
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    login(user, pass) {
        //login stuff, set this.user;
    }

    getUser() {
        return this.user
    }
}
```

I declare the service once, in the bootstrap

```
const SERVICE_PROVIDERS = [
    AuthService
]

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [App],
    providers: [
        SERVICE_PROVIDERS
    ]
})
```

I then use it in several components. Think stuff like the guards around routes, the displaying of basic user details, or displaying the name of the logged in person somewhere. Usage is then like this:

```
export class Login {
    user: User;
    constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.user = this.auth.getUser();
    }
}
```

This way the `AuthService` is instantiated once in every component. This way, the user also does not change *when logging out and back in*. So, I know that the user variable has changed in the service object on my `Login` component, but the `ngOnInit` still fetches the old user object when I navigate there. The guards around my routes also use the old user.

**edit**
It looks like every component has it's own instance of the service, which means they all have their own instance of `user`. I don't want to go back to my database every time I want my logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try below,

```
class Service {
    private _user: Subject<User> = new Subject<User>;
    public get user() : string
    {
        return this._user;
    }

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    login(user, pass) {
        //login stuff, set this.user;
        // after setting user call this.user.next(<new user object>);
    }
}

// using user object
// serviceinstance.user.subscribe(res => { you will get user object here.. })
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Is `Subject` a native object?

Comment: Subject is imported from `'rxjs/Rx'`. While this is a cleaner way of doing this, my problem is still that every component has it's own instance of `Service`, which means that they all have different `user` objects.

Comment: @Jorg What's the point of using a different services for different components? Is this intentional, or something you're just not sure how to fix? If the latter, you should avoid declaring "application" providers in the `@NgModule`. This can lead to multiple instances in some cases. What you should do instead is implement a static `forRoot` in the module. [See here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root)

Comment: @peeskillet It's the same service, and it would be great if it was the same instance (I guess). I'll check out your link.

Comment: @Jorg When doing this, the `forRoot` should only be used for the app module, and all other modules that you import this module it, just use the regular import (without `forRoot`). This is a convention

Comment: @peeskillet I'm coming from angular1.x and I'm still trying to wrap my head around this. Do you have an example?

Comment: @Jorg something like this https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/fad5a907c502a3eee9b16806e08e38ae

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123745/discussion-between-jorg-and-peeskillet).